# Is it possible to implement an authorised DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Given a `DbContext` and a `ClientContext` (custom session data about the user) is it possible create a `DbContext` that is "authorised": where only a subset of the rows on each "table" is available?

With an authorised DbContext I'm trying to have a central row-level authorisation implementation.

I've researched it a bit and the only way to filter out a `DbSet` would be to use something like `Queryable.Where` but that returns an `IQueryable<T>` and there doesn't seem to be a way to return a filtered `DbSet<T>` (except maybe for global queries that you can setup in `Startup` but they don't have access to injected dependencies like `ClientContext`).

Is it possible to define `DbSet<T>` authorisation filters via an injected scoped dependency like `ClientContext`?

Comment: Short answer: no. As you said, global query filters (not "global queries") aren't suitable because they're static in one db model.

Comment: @GertArnold see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19211) - it clearly shows that you could use injected stuff with global query filters as they use **instance** properties of DbContext.

Comment: Please clarify this question by showing some examples of how/what you'd like to filter. If you always want to filter on pre-defined attributes, maybe global query filters can be your friend.

Comment: @GertArnold As I said the only requirement is to be able to inject dependencies somehow and be able to apply filters based on the scoped `ClientContext`.

Comment: Yeah, but don't you understand the dilemma? With global query filters you won't be able to filter on things you didn't pre-configure.

Comment: @GertArnold That's why global filters aren't a good fit from what I can see. Where's the dilemma?

Comment: OK, one last try. You can add predefined [global filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) that may use values set at runtime. But the filter expressions themselves are part of the model in the app domain. So they can't be modified in the life time of the application. So if you always want to filter on, say, `UserId`, that's OK, but you can't add a filter on `UserName` later. That's why it maters how/what/when you want to filter.

Comment: @GertArnold If I have a db context that defines those filters in `OnModelCreating` based on `ClientContext` (injected via constructor) and their lifetime (set with `AddDbContext` in `Startup`) is transient or scoped wouldn't it change those filters based on the `ClientContext`, which may change per request (and therefore many times during the lifetime of the application)?

Comment: No, the are *model level*, and the model is created once. Just set a breakpoint in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @GertArnold Oh I see, then the answer that I've accepted doesn't work. Thanks for letting me notice it.

Answer (score 2):

There are model-level query filters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#model-level-query-filters

From the link:

> This feature allows LINQ query predicates (a boolean expression
>   typically passed to the LINQ Where query operator) to be defined
>   directly on Entity Types in the metadata model (usually in
>   OnModelCreating). Such filters are automatically applied to any LINQ
>   queries involving those Entity Types, including Entity Types
>   referenced indirectly, such as through the use of Include or direct
>   navigation property references.

Example from the link:

```cs
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(
            p => !p.IsDeleted
            && p.TenantId == this.TenantId);
    }
}
```

You can use this for simple scenarios. You define an instance property in your DbContext and in `OnModelCreating` you specify `HasQueryFilter` on any entity you want to filter. The property is an instance property, so if you have a scoped DbContext, the correct property value from that request would be used, which is handy if you want to filter by something from your UserContext. I have personally never tried this so I don't know how complex it allows your implementation to be, but you can play with it.

Comment: As OP said, global query filters don't fit the bill.

Comment: @GertArnold He said `global queries that you can setup in Startup but they don't have access to injected dependencies like ClientContext` and this can't apply to global query filters, because one can set up global query filters to use injected stuff.

Comment: So probably the question isn't clear enough to be answered. What I understand is that OP wants to filter in ways that can't be predicted (= pre-configured), but maybe you're right.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, it can't be pre-configured. Filters depend on `ClientContext` which is a scoped injected dependency. You can't inject services via `DbContext` constructors, right?

Comment: @ShoeDiamente why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Because from what I recall `AddDbContext` requires the `DbContext` to have a default empty constructor and it uses that one to construct it

Comment: @ShoeDiamente you should try https://www.google.com/search?q=ef+core+inject+into+dbcontext - works wonders :)

Comment: Apparently `OnModelCreating` is called once per lifetime of the application so injecting scoped dependencies into the constructor of the dbcontext to then setup query filters in `OnModelCreating` doesn't work. Correct?

Comment: Of course it's called once per lifetime. But I think you and @GertArnold misunderstood each other in the question comments. You setup filters once, but the expression is executed using instance-provided data, and if the instance is a scoped dependency, then that data is scoped too. What he meant to say is that you can't modify the filter once it was set up. You set it only once per model type. When he said filter, he meant filter definition. Data is always provided by DbContext instance at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about EF and EF core, but we abstract the DbContext away into functional specific 'logic' blocks.

e.g:

```
class DbContext()
{
   public DbSet<PeopleEntity> peoples;
}
```

```
class PeopleLogic()
{
   DbContext _context;

   PeopleLogic(DbContext context)
   {
       _context = context;
   }

   IEnumerable GetAllPeoples()
   {
      // create context,
      // apply filters
      // return result
   }
}
```

We ofcourse have a base for simple CRUD operations;

```
public void AddOrUpdate(){
            lock (SyncDatabaseWriteObject)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var context = CreateContext())
                    {
                        //insert the entity and add it to the db context
                        context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate((TEntity)entity);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return entity;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new DatabaseAccessException("Error occured while getting saving.", ex);
                }
            }
}
```

And instead of passing the dbcontext around, we pass around logics.

e.g. we seperate the logic for the database and the access to the database into 2 seperate projects, the business layer then only uses the dbAccess layer.

Comment: If you are suggesting something like the Repository pattern, no thanks. We tried that and we decided against it. EF Core is a good enough repository-like entity and by encapsulating it you lose all the flexibility of LINQ.

Comment: You certainly do not lose the flexbility of linq, you however move it out of the business layer to an abstraction - ill try an add a sample

Comment: Added a simple sample for addOrUpdate, i feel like some more complex stuff we have is company property so i won't share it. But since linq is mostly extensions and so one we have some more complex selector functions where we pass predicates etc and honestly working this way feels super clean.

Comment: You lose the flexibility of LINQ-to-SQL if you mean that returning `IEnumerable` still enables you to use LINQ. Also, Repository vs EF Core is a dead topic for me. There are tens of articles online and I've read many of them and I tried both ways myself. Repository is not worth the effort for me.

Comment: It wouldn't even simplify the problem that much in this instance because there are many different ways I'm reading from a table and I would have to construct N repository methods (or go on into reimplementing LINQ-to-SQL with all the complexity that that entails) that would still need to have a central source of truth for row-level authorisation.

Comment: 'different ways I'm reading from a table ' which you're still doing, however now from a different location, its just a simple abstracttion and you could move some redundant code to bases. anyways ill leave the answer here for any other users that come across this thread if this is not something for you and wish you good luck with finding something else